# Qmake-qt5 set top project directory variable

Tags: qt, qmake

First of all, I read [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir).
I have project developed with qmake-qt4, and i need to port it to qmake-qt5. First of all, i found that solution for setting TOP_PROJECT_DIR variable with .qmake.cache.in in top project directory didn't work in qmake-qt5. But when i moved this code

```
TOP_PROJECT_DIR = $$PWD
```

to .qmake.conf file in top project dir, there are no effect. Variable TOP_PROJECT_DIR is empty in root and other *.pro-files of project. How can i set variable for whole project in one place?